# Give iOS Developer Program membership as a gift?

Tags: developer-program

Is it possible to purchase a one-year iOS Developer Program membership for someone as a gift? I know the Apple ID of the desired recipient, but couldn't find how to offer the program membership.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to give them the money to buy. Unlike software and hardware it's [more like] a contract so it's best for the person to be involved from the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Apple checks each developer's identity by checking with their credit card company, so it has to be paid with the developers credit card.

There are other ways involving faxing ID to them, but that's rather inconvenient.

Comment: Unfortunate, but thanks for the info!